# How to run docker image local machine?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm creating a react app and add that project into docker. It is a fresh react project and I didn't change anything there. I followed all the steps of this video tutorial. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSIC3JTQnPs&t=3s). When I run my docker image using "docker run -it react-test bash" this command. It successfully runs the image but it does not load the website of my project.

[image: my console]

[image: error in website]

after that, I tried with "docker run -it -p 8082:8082 react-test" this code to run it in 8082 port. It starts the console like above and I changed address into "http://localhost:8082" and  "http://172.17.0.2:8082" and run them. But getting the same error. Web page not loading. How can I fix this?

**This is my folder structure and dockerfile.**

[image: dockerfile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your react application is running on 3000 port by default.expose 3000 port and do port mapping OR change default port to your choice and expose container on that port.Make sure you can access exposed port from browser.(if not do the tunneling with particular port).

```
docker run -itd -p 3000:3000 react-test
```

run docker in detach mode(-d) so you don't need to exit from container all time